# Node.js mysql loop only showing the last entry

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, for-loop, electron

I've seen this question asked and answered here but I can't seem to get it to work for myself: my javascript mysql loop is only showing the last entry from the database. I'm building a simple internal wiki in electron and I'm trying to list some categories that are stored in a mysql database.

```html
<script>
const mysql = require('mysql');
const marked = require('marked');
var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'database'
});
db.connect();

$sqlnav = 'SELECT * FROM categories;'
db.query($sqlnav, function(error, rows, fields){
  if (error) throw error;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    console.log(rows[i]);
    $('nav > ul').html('<li>' + rows[i].category + '</li>');
  }
});
</script>
<nav>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The console.log is showing each row correctly, but there is only one list item being displayed in the html.

Some of the other answers have indicated that I'm simply overwriting the same instance with each iteration of the loop, I'm just having trouble understanding how to get out of that. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.append()` instead of `.html()` so you add items instead of overwriting it every time.

From the JQuery docs:

`When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.`

Comment: Thanks! That worked; didn't even consider it being jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Build and append an html string in the for loop, then call $().html outside of the loop.